# Booleans в JS

Tags: javascript

Решился на изучение JS, только вот застрял. Никак не могу логический оператор понять. Задание такое:

Напишите код, который вернет `true`, если в строке "I'm coding like a champ!" более 10 символов. Вы можете просто записать условие в редакторе и оно будет оценено для Вас.

Объясните, как малознающему.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишут, мол, напишите так:

```
"I'm coding like a champ!".length>10
```

и сразу получите `true`.

Comment: Спасибо. Я почему то решил, что нужно уловие if добавить.